# Shopify plus admin/api/2019-04/users/current.json this api is not working

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

When I call this api via private app, it returns example data, not the original data. Does anyone know why?

When I call the api, i'm receiving some fake response

**Request GET:**

```
https://XXXX.myshopify.com/admin/api/2019-04/users/current.json
```

**Response from shopify:**

```
{
    "user": {
        "id": null,
        "first_name": "",
        "email": "pixels@jadedpixel.com",
        "url": null,
        "im": null,
        "screen_name": null,
        "phone": null,
        "last_name": "Shopify API",
        "account_owner": false,
        "receive_announcements": 0,
        "bio": null,
        "permissions": [],
        "locale": "en",
        "user_type": "guest_api",
        "phone_validated?": false,
        "tfa_enabled?": false
    }
}
```